# v-for in VueJS, how to keep track of previous components data?

Tags: vuejs2

I would like to output a series of entries, which contains a value.

But for each line, I would like to display the sum of all values from start to the current line.

For example:

```
// App.vue

<template>
    <div>
        <Row v-for="item in items" :value="item.value"/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
          items: [{ value: 3}, {value: 5}, {value: 1}, {value: 9}, {value: 3}]
        }
    }
</script>


// Row.vue

<template>
    <div>{{ value }} (Sum: <subtotal here>)</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['value']
    }
</script>
```

I would like this output :

```
<div>
    <div>3 (Sum: 3)</div>
    <div>5 (Sum: 8)</div>
    <div>1 (Sum: 9)</div>
    <div>9 (Sum: 18)</div>
    <div>3 (Sum: 21)</div>
</div>
```

I already tried multiple way, emitting an event on `Row` creating/updating, using a local variable in `App`...

Using a local non-reactive variable causes bad behavior when updating a component. And using prop ou event cause an infinite loop.

How could I sum progressively each item value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a computed property to keep the count for you:

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    template: '#template',
    data: {
        items: [{ value: 3}, {value: 5}, {value: 1}, {value: 9}, {value: 3}]
    },
    computed: {
        calculatedItems() {
            const newArray = [];
            let sum = 0;
            for(let i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
                sum += this.items[i].value;
                newArray.push({
                    total: sum,
                    item: this.items[i],
                });
            }
            return newArray;
        },
    },
})
```

```html
<!-- development version, includes helpful console warnings -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>





<template id="template">
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in calculatedItems">
            {{ item.item.value }},
            Total: {{ item.total }}
    </div>
</template>
```

This basically makes a copy of your list, and calculates the total values for every entry, this is also more performing that looping for every item to count the values, as this only loops 1 time, and the value is cached

Comment: Thanks. I'm a bit rusty... ^^